# Formdata not upload multiple images

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I use array to add or remove mutli files to upload ,
the proplem that when i want to upload files by ajax and formdata it's not work in my php file and i can't catch the uploaded file here is my upload function.

```js
var upload_images=[];//here where i saved files
function upload_images(){
    const fd = new FormData();
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    fd.append('upload_images[]',upload_images[]);
    xhr.open('POST','upload.php', true);
    xhr.send(fd);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            upload_images=[];
            let i=0;i2=upload_url.length;
            for(let i=0;i<i2;i++){URL.revokeObjectURL(upload_url[i]);}
            upload_url=[];

        }
    };

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
          progress_bar.value=Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
        }
      }, false);


}
```

Comment: Is this function triggered by an `<input type="file"/>` element? You do know that `upload_images[]` is invalid syntax?

Comment: i get the files from `<input type="file"/>` and save then in `upload_images` array when user finish from add or remove files press on sent button then the function trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upload_images[]` accesses the `undefined` property of the array.

If you want to pass an array into a method, don't put `[]` on the end.

However, you don't want to do that.

You want to attach **each** file to the FormData:

```
upload_images.forEach( image =>  fd.append('upload_images[]', image) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put array as is ,you must append each file from array to formdata then send it .

```js
let x=upload_images.length;
for(let i=0;i<x;i++){
fd.append('upload_images[]',upload_images[i]);
}
```